# realtime : Please set pin numbering mode using GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) or GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Tags: gpio

I have a program to remove the output from the sensor for 10 seconds, and if one of the sensors meets the requirements, then the gpio 38 and 37 turn on ..
but this program should be realtime, but when the output comes out once, it is error.
with time.sleep (10)

[image]
[image]

plis help me.. thankyouu before:)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use GPIO.cleanup() until you want the script to exit.**

Comment: wah its work! thankyou so much:)